# How show corresponding key binding of command during M-x completion?

Tags: key-bindings, ido

Linux Mint 20

Emacs 27.2

ido-mode

When I press `M-x` then show (ido-mode) the list of functions.

[image: List of functions]

Nice. But sometime it is not enough. I need to know what is keybinding for this functions. Is it possible to show keybining when  press `M-x` ?

Comment: I don't know if this is possible with ido. `helm` does this, but helm is a really big package with lots of features beyond ido.

Comment: [Icicles](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles) shows you key bindings next to the command names in `*Completions*`. Vanilla Emacs doesn't do that, as far as I know. But as @db48x's answer says, you can always stop and use `C-h f` to find out what a command is bound to.

Comment: `ivy/counsel/swiper` does this too.

Comment: Plain `M-x` in Emacs 28 does this by default too.

Comment: @Basil What do you mean about Emacs 28? It's not exist. Last version of OFFICIAL Emacs is 27.2  https://mirror.ihost.md/gnu/emacs/windows/

Comment: @a_subscriber I'm referring to the current development version of Emacs, that will be officially released in the future as Emacs 28. You can see the current list of upcoming features and changes here: https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/etc/NEWS. For the feature in question, search for `suggest-key-bindings`.

Answer (score 1):

The [amx](https://github.com/DarwinAwardWinner/amx) package will provide this:

> **Showing keyboard shortcuts for commands**
>
> When completing command names, Amx shows the keyboard shortcut for all commands currently bound to a key, so you can find out when there's an easier way to run the command you're looking for.

Ie, `M-x find-file` may appear similar to this, depending on themes and other packages:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `C-h f` to get all the help about any function, including what keys it is bound to.

Comment: I know about C-h f, but I want interactively show keybinding